# Postfix on laptop instead of Mail Client?

Tags: mail, mta

I'd like to send and receive emails via shell, preferably reading and writing with VIM. Do I understand the internet correctly that I should install postfix or exim on my laptop and connect it somehow to e.g. Gmail to do what I want or is there an easier way?